# android Send multi parameter in post method to WCF service by using retrofit lib?

Tags: java, android, wcf, retrofit

I should send 4 parameters with post method in

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
       UriTemplate = "CustomerInsertPost/{Username}/{Password}/{lan}/{Cust}")]
    int CustomerInsertPost(string Username, string Password, string lan, string Cust);
```

by using retrofit library.

the question what the format post retrofit method to this "CustomerInsertPost" ?

Answer (score 1):

The first example on http://square.github.io/retrofit/ is

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

If this also works with POST requests, you are almost there.

Comment: Insert Error: com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody Bad Request '@GET("CustomerInsertPost/{Username}/{Password}/{lan}/{Cust}")
    Call<Customer> customerInsert(@Path("Username")  String userName, @Path("Password") String Pass
            , @Path("lan")  String lan, @Path("Cust")  String customer);'